# Is it possible to do automatic declaration of variabes in loop? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, variables

I'm doing my school homework. I have class named "Person" and using this class, user must add a name to an object of Person class, his surname and so on. I was thinking, would it be possible to automatically define variables in loop? I have a loop where user inputs person's data. Loop would look like this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Input name of  person no. {0}: ", n);
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Input surname of person no. {0}", n);
    surname = Console.ReadLine();

    Person pers+n = new Person(name, surname);
    arr[n] = pers+n;
   }
```

So the declaration of a variable would be something like pers+n. I have no idea how I would define Person objects in this loop the other way around. Thanks!

Comment: Certainly, just go ahead: `string name =`

Comment: You're thinking "I'm creating the n'th person" - but you're not. You're just creating *a* person and then put it in the n'th place of your array. Or maybe I'm not getting you right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
   {
    Console.WriteLine("Input name of  person no. {0}: ", n);
    name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Input surname of person no. {0}", n);
    surname = Console.ReadLine();

    Person pers = new Person(name, surname);
    arr[n] = pers;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a list object

```
         List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
         for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Input name of  person no. {0}: ", n);
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input surname of person no. {0}", n);
            surname = Console.ReadLine();

            Person newPerson = new Person(name, surname);
            people.Add(newPerson);
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to hold a collection of persons.

```
public class Persons: List<Person> {}
```

and Create an instance of this collection of `Persons` outside the loop, and then inside the loop add each new `Person` to this collection .

```
Persons = new Persons();
for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Input name of  person no. {0}: ", n);
   name = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("Input surname of person no. {0}", n);
   surname = Console.ReadLine();
   persons.Add(new Person(name, surname));
}
```

The individual `Person` objects in the collection can be accessed just like an array `persons[index]`

Answer (score 0):

SimpleVar answered my problem. Thanks!
Solution:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
{
Console.WriteLine("Input name of  person no. {0}: ", n);
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Input surname of person no. {0}", n);
surname = Console.ReadLine();

Person pers = new Person(name, surname);
arr[n] = pers;
}
```

I

Comment: This is my answer

Comment: @Eldeniz don't be petty, we helped him.

Comment: @SimpleVar I agree with you but I want that he accepted my answer